Why do these dart generics compile, even though it throws a `TypeError`? What are some ways to fix it?
I wrote some dart code today, which essentially boils down to this:
extension MapCounting<ItemT> on Map<ItemT, num> {
  num get maxValue => values.reduce((max, value) => (max < value)? value : max);
}

Now, imagine I have a main() method like this:
void main() {
  Map<String, int> myMap = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
  };
  var count = myMap.maxValue; // valid because Map<String, int> is a valid subtype
}

The above code doesn't throw compile-time errors. However, if you run it, you'll get this error:
TypeError: Instance of '(num, num) => num': type '(num, num) => num' is not a subtype of type '(int, int) => int'
I think I understand why it's an error -- really, the crux of it comes down to how my "reducer" function only returns num when it needs to return int. This is because Map<String, int>.reduce() expects a int Function(int, int), and my definition can only guarantee it's a num Function(...).
I have two questions regarding this:

Why does the compiler not catch this as an error? Shouldn't it?
How can I fix my extension (nicely)?

I technically found an answer to my second question, but it basically involves rewriting my code outside the extension. Is it possible to do it with a get maxValue getter inside the extension?



Why does the compiler not catch this as an error? Shouldn't it?


It compiles because:

The MapCounting<ItemT> extension is legal on its own.
As you already noted, Dart treats Map<String, int> as a subtype of Map<String, num>.  In general, treating Generic<Derived> as a subtype of Generic<Base> often is convenient, but there are a number of cases where it's not actually safe.

The compiler can't determine that applying a legal extension to (what it considers to be) a legal subtype won't work at runtime.


How can I fix my extension (nicely)?


Don't use num.  Make your extension work on the actual num subtype:
extension MapCounting<ItemT, N extends num> on Map<ItemT, N> {
  N get maxValue => values.reduce((max, value) => (max < value)? value : max);
}


I could have sworn I had tried using a generic N type, but it didn't work for some reason... Oh well, you example works. Thanks for your explanation!
